# convert dataframe that contains hourly time series to ts object in r

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I have data of the form:

```
   Date                PJMW_MW
1  2002-04-01 01:00:00 4374
2  2002-04-01 02:00:00 4306
3  2002-04-01 03:00:00 4322
4  2002-04-01 04:00:00 4359
5  2002-04-01 05:00:00 4436
6  2002-04-01 06:00:00 4723
7  2002-04-01 07:00:00 5180
8  2002-04-01 08:00:00 5482
9  2002-04-01 09:00:00 5616
10 2002-04-01 10:00:00 5722
...
143206 2018-08-03 00:00:00 5489
```

And the data are of the following type:

```
> class(dat)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(dat$Date)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> class(dat$PJMW_MW)
[1] "numeric"
> typeof(dat$PJMW_MW)
[1] "double"
```

How can I convert this into a time series object so that when I plot the data the x axis is the actual dates (and not indices from 1 to 143206)? I would also need to do time series analysis like forecasts, smoothing, fitting models etc.

What is the recommended way of handling such data for these purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With base R, you can use the function `ts()`, where you specify the values of your serie, and the start and end times of your observations, but it seems it is not appropriate with hours.

So you can use the function `zoo()` (from the library **zoo**) :

```
library(zoo)

hourly_ts <- zoo(
  x         = dat$PJMW_MW,
  order.by  = dat$Date,
  frequency = 24
)
```

Then if you `plot(hourly_ts)` (or with **ggplot**) it will have the right x-axis.

Comment: So per unit of time means per day? In the Help documentation it is also phrased "per unit of time", but I guess they always mean per day then...

Comment: the argument `frequency` from `ts()` function is not appropriate with hours. Library **zoo** will be more appropriate for you. It edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason r thinks this time series is irregular... Probably because there are a few NA values in the Date column. Is there a way I can make it a regular ts object? Or a regular zoo?

Comment: can we have access to the full dataset ? In general, missing values doesn't create problem with time series. Are there rows with missing values for PJMW, or these rows don't exist in the dataset ?